# jQuery - Selecting DOM element, difference between using element.name_class or element[class*=name_class]

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Lately I've found a lot of jQuery expressions selecting the DOM element with element[class*=name_class]. I've been always using element.name_class, is there any difference between them, or it's just a style matter?

```
span[class*=orden_bloque]       VS    span.orden_bloque
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's different

The first one will select the class with exact name as `name_class`

The second one select `any` class name that **[contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)** `name_class`

`span[class*=orden_bloque]` will select all `span` elements that contain string `orden_bloque` inside their class name

`span.orden_bloque` will select all `span` elements with exact class name as `orden_bloque`

Answer (score 1):

`span[class*=orden_bloque]` vs `span.orden_bloque` can produce different results. Consider the following example:

```
<span class="orden_bloque"></span>
<span class="orden_bloque_foobar"></span>
```

- `span[class*=orden_bloque]` matches both spans
- `span.orden_bloque` matches the first

The [`*=` and similar selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) can be used to select classes that have matching substrings.

Answer (score 0):

For:

```
span[class*=orden_bloque]
```

this will mathch all the span element that has class contain orden_bloque

On second case:

```
pan.orden_bloque
```

this will mathch all the span element that has class orden_bloque